# Update Cart via Shopify API on Quantity Change

Tags: shopify

I'm having trouble updating the cart via the Shopify API. The code I'm using is below:

```
  <!-- Quantity Box on Cart Page -->
  <script>
    $('.qty_wrap .qty_button').on('click', function(){
      var qty = $(this).parent('.qty_wrap').find('.qty_input').val();
      var currentVariant = $(this).parent('.qty_wrap').find('.qty_input').attr("data-variant");

      var subTotal = $(this).parents('.card').find('#subtotal').text();
      var loopKey = $(this).parents('.card').attr("data-key");

      if($(this).hasClass('qty_plus')) {
        qty++;
      }else {
        if(qty > 1) {
          qty--;
        }
      }
      $(this).parent('.qty_wrap').find('.qty_input').val(qty);
      console.log(loopKey);
      console.log(qty);
      $.post('/cart/change.js', { id: loopKey, quantity: qty });
    });
  </script>
```

I'm using the line key as the ID, I've also tried variant ID's though this isn't suggested by the docs. Any help would be great, no errors are coming back via the console.

Comment: Need to check on the live, code can't any idea regarding the issue

Answer (score 0):

Was an out of stock item causing an issue. Doesn't report back any errors.

Comment: return the results into network tab, console panel